# Why can't I get the nickname of the user who issued / removed the role?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to find out who has removed / issued a role from the logs, but it does not come out
I tried in different ways but it didn't work out, please help.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'guildMemberUpdate',
    once: false,
    async execute(oldMember, newMember) {
        try {
            const fetchedLogs = await newMember.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
                limit: 1,
                type: 'MEMBER_UPDATE',
            });
            const memberLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
            if (!memberLog) return console.log(`${newMember.displayName} sam`);
            const { executor, target } = memberLog;


            if (oldMember.roles.cache.size < newMember.roles.cache.size) {
                const role = newMember.roles.cache.difference(oldMember.roles.cache).first();
                if (entry.target.id === newMember.user.id) {
                    console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString('ru-RU', { timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow', hour12: false })} Роль: ${role.name} выдал - ${executor.tag} пользователю - ${newMember.displayName} - <@${newMember.user.id}>`)
                }
                if (oldMember.roles.cache.size > newMember.roles.cache.size) {
                    const role = newMember.roles.cache.difference(oldMember.roles.cache).first();
                    if (entry.target.id === newMember.user.id) {
                        console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString('ru-RU', { timeZone: 'Europe/Moscow', hour12: false })} Роль: ${role.name} снял - ${executor.tag} пользователю - ${newMember.displayName} - <@${newMember.user.id}>`)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`)
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GuildAuditLogsEntry.executor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) is a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) instance. To get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) version with nickname, roles etc. you can look for the user in the `GuildMember`'s guild. This is how you can do it:

```js
newMember.guild.members.resolve(executor)
```

Keep in mind this relies on cache. Fetching is also an option (it's a promise!):

```js
await newMember.guild.members.fetch(executor.id)
```

Comment: Those *are* the examples...

Comment: What do you mean *real*? That is *real* code